# Are there limitations on size or record count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Are there any limitations to MySQL such as size or record limits?

The biggest tables in the database I am working on have over 150,000 rows.  Will MySQL be able to handle that?

Comment: have a look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/can-mysql-reasonably-perform-queries-on-billions-of-rows

Comment: Did you check the manual? 150k records is next to nothing...

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple resources from the docs on MySQL limitations.

> Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables. [[src]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html)

> There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table.  [[src]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html)

> Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. [[src]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html)

---

Bottom line is, MySQL can easily handle your scenario.

Comment: The rowsize max is confusing -- BLOBs and TEXTs do not count toward the 64KB limit.

Comment: BLOBs and TEXT do count somewhat towards the limit, but you're right, it's not as simple as saying 64KB row size

Answer (score 2):

A million rows -- not a problem.  A billion rows -- that gets interesting.

Many of the 'hard' limits are here:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,25724,224521 (and a subsequent post)

Some 'practical' limits are posted here:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots

A column can be 4GB (LONGTEXT or LONGBLOB), but there are other limits that may prevent you from actually creating that fat a record.